# regex for 2 numbers and a sign

Tags: regex, preg-match

I need a preg_match with regex for control a number input.

User has to enter a number between 1-80.
But after 1-80 so the 3rd input can be a + sign or ^.

So 1-80 is possible, but 79+ or 61^ has to be possible

Is this possible with regex?

My code now:

```
[0-7][0-9]|80
```

But now i cant enter 1-9 in the input.
Who can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part `[0-7][0-9]` can also match `00` and matches at least 2 characters.

You can use

```
^(?:[1-9]|[1-7][0-9]|80)[+^]?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[1-9]` Match a digit 1-9
  - `|` Or
  - `[1-7][0-9]` Match 10-79
  - `|` Or
  - `80` Match literally
- `)` Close group
- `[+^]?` Optionally match `+` or `^` (where `^` should not be at the start of the character class)
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jQxYdj/1)

Comment: `^` should not be at the start of the character class, important point.

Comment: I think `[\^+]` would be better than `[+^]?`. Then you don't have to make sure "^" is last

Comment: @Jesper You can do that as well, it just should not be the first character or else it would denote a negated character class.